# Why function won't modify this array

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Function won't modify passed arr when calling this function:

```
const animalTypes = [
  new Animal( "wolf", "audio/wolf.mp3" ),
  new Animal( "frog", "audio/frog.wav" ),
  new Animal( "cow", "audio/cow.mp3" ),
  new Animal( "snake", "audio/snake.mp3" ) 
];

function randomAnimalArray( arr, n ) {
  arr = [];
  for ( let i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    arr.push( animalTypes[ Math.floor( Math.random() * animalTypes.length ) ] );
  }
}
```

But it will when calling this function:

```
function testy(arr) {

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i]++;
  }
}
```

I use it like that. And the console is showing []

```
let solutionArr = [], guessesArr = [];

function computerIsPlaying() {
  let animalNumberEl = document.getElementById("animals-number");
  randomAnimalArray(solutionArr, animalNumberEl.value);
  console.log(solutionArr);
  for (let i = 0; i < solutionArr.length; i++) {
    solutionArr[i].makeSound();
  }
}
```

Comment: What language is this in? That's kind of crucial information, so please add it as a tag.

Comment: Because you're replacing whatever array you pass in with a new array in `arr = []`. You can't modify the *variable* `arr` *by reference*.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't modify the passed array in your first function because your redeclaring what array is within in the function itself. This means that the original reference to the array is lost and instead your modifying the array inside the function. If your `return arr` at the end of your function you will notice that the inner array has in fact changed.

In your second example, you're passing the array into your function, but not redeclaring it, allowing your for loop to act upon the passed in array.

Thus, if you stick with the code in your first example and add `return arr` after your for loop, you can get the new array in your `computerIsPlaying` function:

```
function computerIsPlaying() {
  let animalNumberEl = document.getElementById("animals-number");
  solutionArr = randomAnimalArray(solutionArr, animalNumberEl.value);
  console.log(solutionArr);
  for (let i = 0; i < solutionArr.length; i++) {
    solutionArr[i].makeSound();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinitializing the parameter destroys its reference:

```
arr = [];
```

Setting its length to 0 will *not* destroy the reference, and it will serve the same purpose:

```
arr.length = 0;
```